# My Own Cascade Classifier: Can not get new positive sample. The most possible reason is insufficient count of samples in given vec-file

Tags: opencv3.0, cascade, object-detection, haar-classifier

I want to create my own cascade classifier to detect windows. I'm using Cascade Trainger Gui. I have 2805 positive images and 2718 negatives, but when I try to build my classifier then I get this error:

> Can not get new positive sample. The most possible reason is
>   insufficient count of samples in given vec-file.

I decreased my positive Image usage to 10 and min hit rate to 0,5 but this still isn't working.

[Here is Github link](https://github.com/wpadka/Cascade-Clasifier/tree/master/Cascade) with all files.

Comment: minor grammatical improvements and addition of block quote

Comment: link descriptor